# Unity 5.4. Turn child's mesh renderer in Multiplayer

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I want to have people walk around in scenes in multiplayer. At a time I want to turn the body's mesh renderer off. 
(body is a child's object)
so I wrote 
`Body.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().enabled = false;` 
in the Networkbehaviour script. Unfortunately this won't be synced in the network.

How can I sync this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Unity UNET.

1. Create a boolean.
2. Mark it as [SyncVar]
3. Write a hook function. That hook function will be called automatically by UNET when boolean variable changes its value.

Link: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html

```
[SyncVar(hook = "OnSomeValueChange")]
public bool isMeshEnabled;

public void OnSomeValueChange(bool valueToChangeTo)
{
     isMeshEnabled = valueToChangeTo;
     // Enable/Disable client's mesh here
}
```